# How to make painted texture a seperate object?

Tags: texturing, materials

I am not sure if the question makes sense. Basically, I have a texture, I painted white lines on it, now is it possible to make the white lines a separate object? The main goal is to make the white stripes extrude a little from the object, like a little bump.

Comment: if it's just "a little bump" you can just fake the volume with a Bump node

Comment: Do I just connect the texture into a bump node into output volume? I am fairly new to blender.

Comment: I guess my texture is a little too complicated. May I send you the blend file to check out?

Comment: Sorry I meant Normal input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: it depends on the texture, if this is just white and black stripes, yes it will work fine if you plug the texture into the height of a Bump node, and plug this Bump into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF, it will fake a bit of volume as you'll see

Comment: you can pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The blend file was too large to use pasteall. I uploaded them here - https://we.tl/t-UKyNKHAMfl

Comment: This is the setup that should work, the problem is that Blender doesn't manage well the bitmap pictures as bump images, it gives artefacts, unlike procedural texture images, I don't know how to fix this: https://zupimages.net/up/22/09/n0pr.jpg  the used images generally need to be openEXR, 32-Bit Float, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem here

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help.

Comment: With a ColorRamp between the ImageTexture and the Bump nodes you can get rid of the artifacts on the white strips. For the left color use 808080 and push the sliders a bit together. At the borders of the strips still will look a bit jagged. That's because you use a 1k texture but the leg only uses 1/4 of the image. The result is pixelated. Consider a better UV unwrap or a 2k texture. Since your model is fairly high-poly you could also sculpt the details in (or use a displacement modifier) and bake a normal map later for a low-poly version.